# How to automatically disable customer account after payment failures?

Tags: magento2, customer-account

Is there a plug-in to automatically disable a customer's account after a certain number of payment failures? My store is undergoing a carding attack. The attacker is using different IP addresses and is using email addresses from gmail, so this seems like the only way to stop it. The attacker is doing this by calling my site's API so captcha is useless here.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the CAPTCHA for the checkout so it will prevent carding via the API. Depending on the Magento version you are on, if it is available I would enable reCAPTCHA v3 as it it basically invisible to the end user unless Google needs to verify they are human.